# Angularjs comes back with undefined token values

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have a cookie that I am making in .net, the value of which is encoded to base 64, and is being decoded with .net also. I just want to check if the cookie exists and has a value in an angular function, the angular function that passes this off to the .net worked before I started encoding.

```
    var CookieVal = $scope.cookieStore.get('CookieName');
    if (typeof CookieVal == 'undefined') {
        $scope.location.path("/login");
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
```

The problem with this is that it every time this runs it gives me the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token C
```

What the token is changes and is always after a numeric.

What I think is the answer is that it is trying to decrypt the cookie value and getting confused by it but I cant be sure on that. Is there anyway for it to just check if its null/undefined without it trying to read the value?

Comment: Post the whole function , there is a **syntax error** in your code!

Comment: There is nothing more besides the start (var checkAuth = function ($scope) {) and closing tag (}).

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace?